# mysql find a word that start with # in string (sentence) and get its count

Tags: mysql, select, count

I want to find words that start with `#` in the sentence column from my table author. i don't know the words i am loking for all i know is that it starts with `#`.

table : author(name, sentence)

**author | sentence**
albert | I #want to be #discussing with #you
david  | tonight #discussing #part 1
sam    | The result will be #you
david  | #you #knew nothing
betty  | #This is #pretty

The result will be like :
**word        | count**
want        |  1
discussing  |  2
part        |  1
you         |  3
this        |  1

**What i tried:**
I did:

```
select * from author where sentence like ?", "#%"
```

It gets part of the sentence beginning with #.

```
#want to be #discussing with #you
#discussing #part 1    
#you   
#you #knew nothing   
#This is #pretty
```

but how do get the query to iterate in through the sentence?

Comment: Have you tried anything? How structured is the data, can you do a count of '#' in the string?

Comment: @KsaR: It is not since I don't know the words i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get it by following this syntax..

`SELECT * FROM author WHERE sentence LIKE '#%'`